# NiFi: Filter topic while consuming from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

There is a batch topic(`Json` content) in kafka that has to be consumed through `NiFi(version 1.8)`.
I'm able to consume this topic using `consumekafkarecord` processor but would like to filter based on an attribute value
as I don't need all the records from that topic.

Can the filter be done while consuming the kafka topic `even before getting the records into NiFi`? What would be the best approach for this like what `Processors` or `Scripts` to use ?

I just want to filter out huge number of records based on one of the attribute values as they are not needed.

Comment: when you say "attributes" you mean the value of a field in each record (json) ?

Comment: Yes exactly Bryan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way I know of to filter records inside of ConsumeKafkaRecord, but you can do this easily right after that processor.

One option would be to connect it to a QueryRecord processor and write a SQL statement that selects the records you are interested in.

A second option would be to use PartitionRecord which allows you to partition records based on a record path expression. So you can say partition on field1, and if there are two values like A and B, then it will produce two flow files, one containing all records with A and one containing all records with B, then you just route the one you are interested in, and send the other one to a dead-end.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. In case of option 1, how would I write SQL statements to retrieve nested json attributes. Can you point to some examples?

Comment: Take a look at the addition details link from the processor docs, there is an example with hierarchical data - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html